# Bigquery kafka sink connect not accepting boolean values

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

Schemaless Bigquery kafka sink connector SMT not able to save data to bigquery on boolean.

MapsUtil.debugPrint on recordValue before returning from `apply(R record)`.

```
active = true java.lang.String
```

Schema definition

```
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "active",
    "type": "BOOLEAN"
  }
```

Deserialiser

```
public class BooleanDeserialiser extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

@Override
public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
        throws IOException {
    return !"0".equals(parser.getText());
}
```

Serialiser

```
public class BooleanSerialiser extends JsonSerializer<Boolean> {

@Override
public void serialize(Boolean value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException {
    gen.writeString(value ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Error

```
    [row index 76]: invalid: Cannot convert string value to boolean: 1
at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.maybeThrowEncounteredErrors(KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.java:108)
at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.put(BigQuerySinkTask.java:233)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:539)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Just to confirm, Its about this [connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery)?? If, so Its this a bug report? I think you should report it to the [proper channel](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/issues) of the connector github project.

Comment: @betjens agree, but without SMT it is working fine hence the question.

Comment: On that matter then you should open an issue there and wait for reply. It should come soon. meanwhile about your issue `invalid: Cannot convert string value to boolean: 1`  have your check your datatypes? what is the raw string value you are getting?

Comment: @Betjens as mentioned in the question, it is (string) "true". I tried with (string) "1" and without any specific serializer but the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking more on have the communication done before actually running into the casting. Please check the comment on your issue case it have been updated.

Comment: By looking at the response by the devs from the project. You can rise a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685) and ask to product team to implement the feature.

Comment: thanks @Betjens. Will followup with google. As per suggestion on official github issue, have tried first with google [insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) and [insert all](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll), `1/0` is not supported when automated schema is on - string`true/false` worked at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaving this as community wiki response for community visibility for this kind of questions. As mention on your question made to the [connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/issues/176) devs, your request may need a feature implemented on bigquery that needs to be requested to by opening a [BigQuery Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685). This will bring this kind of requests into developers spotlight so it can be taken into consideration.

It's worth to mention, you can see the list of issues/bugs for the confluentinc kafka-connect-bigquery on the project [issue dashboard](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/issues).

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217251993 Issue created